# No snowflake on stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, top-bar, stackexchange.com, winter-bash

It looks weird that [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) has no snowflake on the topbar:

> [image: Screenshot of top bar on stackexchange.com illustrating missing snowflake icon]

Especially when [Winter Bash page](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/) located on it and the welcome message begins with "Stack Exchange" link:

> [image: Screenshot of winterbash2017.stackexchange.com showing link to stackexchange.com]

I recommend adding a snowflake icon to the [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) topbar too.

Comment: Different code base, which means double work. If it will be added there it means any changes would take more time. So maybe better without it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Seems that **all** of your recent comments are about **don't do anything, leave as is** :)

Comment: Maybe it's just panic, as I want the team to work on the "bigger" bugs and requests. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard **my bugz beat your bugz** :)

Answer (score 4):

Stackexchange.com has different code, which is why the new top bar didn't show up there immediately either.  (Also chat, which also does not have the snowflake.)  Since most of us spend most of our time on the actual Q&A sites, it doesn't make sense to have developers spend time adding the snowflake to the places that don't share the same code.

I assume that if it were cost-effective to make the same code drive the top bar on all pages they'd already be doing that.

It does look weird, I agree.

Comment: Well I don't see the snowflake on **any** SE site ... :/ which appears to be a bug in the top nav choices script.

Comment: I'm not surprised that adding something to the top bar affected the script that rearranges the top bar.  I guess you'll need to fix it, ask the author to fix it, turn it off, or do without the snowflake.  Bummer, but not SE's bug this time. :-)

Comment: Yeah, bug has been reported :) It's not important as there are other ways of seeing what hats I've got :)