# Winter/Summer Bash snowflake is not appearing on the top bar of the main site (Stack Exchange)

Tags: bug, top-bar, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

I am not sure if this is intended, but I don't see the Winter/Summer Bash snowflake notification on the top bar of the main site (https://stackexchange.com).

It shows me the same inbox as on the other sites, so it's obviously linked to my account (even if it didn't update the avatar). I guess that it's coded differently, as there are neither reputation nor badges to display, but why not put the snowflake? (Or the *help* icon)

On https://stackexchange.com:

[image]

On meta.stackexchange:

[image]

Comment: It's always been like this, see [No snowflake on stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304406/no-snowflake-on-stackexchange-com).